# Chromium custom build running too slow

Tags: performance, build, chromium

I have followed instructions here:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

to compile chormium on Windows 7 x64.

It takes some long time to compile, but the problem is not the slow compiling, the problem is in fact that when the browser i built, it runs very, very slow. Is uses much more RAM then usual Chome and it even cannot run on Virtual Machine with 3GB of RAM (shows error).

How can I compile Chromium that can run normally without performanse problems?

Answer (score 4):

If you built it according to instructions then I suppose the problem was in `"is_debug = true"`.
In case you want build browser for normal usage try to change this string from dev manual from:

```
gn gen out/Default --args="is_component_build = true is_debug = true"
```

to

```
gn gen out/Default --args="is_official = true"
```

"is_officail" flag makes a lot of optimizasions.

Answer (score 1):

see https://www.chromium.org/developers/gn-build-configuration
for full gn-docs

you most likely need

```
is_official_build = true
is_debug = false
dcheck_always_on = false
blink_symbol_level = 0
symbol_level = 0
```

in your gn args.